# Imprimir un presupuesto sacando los datos de un sqlite

Tags: c#, visual-studio, windows-forms, sqlite, report

estoy haciendo un programa con el que una pequeña empresa pueda crear presupuestos de una manera sencilla.
El caso es que decidí usar sqlite porque no necesitan una gran cantidad de datos guardados.
Para le proyecto, tengo objetos clientes, objetos cristales, i varias cosas mas, pero para probar el report de momento con clientes y cristales hay suficiente.

Entonces, puedo consultar, agregar o eliminar datos en la base de datos sin problema.
El problema lo tengo a la hora de crear el presupuesto.
Tengo métodos para sacar la información del sqlite, pero me encuentro que solo puedo pasarle los datos al report por un objeto, en este caso cliente, con el codigo siguiente;

```
public partial class FormPresupuesto : Form
{
    Presupuesto ultimo = new Presupuesto();
    Cliente cliente = new Cliente();
    public FormPresupuesto()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        ultimo = SqliteDataAccess.BuscarUltimoPresupuestoCreado()[0];
        cliente = SqliteDataAccess.BuscarClientePorDNI(ultimo.ClienteDNI)[0];
    }        

    private void FormPresupuesto_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        this.ClienteBindingSource.DataSource = cliente;
        this.reportViewer1.RefreshReport();
    }

}
```

Con ese código puedo pasar la información del cliente al report, y la información del presupuesto.
Pero el report solo me muestra la información del ultimo objeto que le pase.
Si le paso el objeto cliente, me pondrá correctamente lo datos del cliente. Si le paso el objeto presupuesto me pasará correctamente los datos del presupuesto (la fecha y el número, pero la información la machaca, no me escribe la información de ambos objetos.

Entiendo que no es la manera correcta de hacerlo, y me gustaria que alguien me orientara un poco en como hacerlo correctamente por favor.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Si necesitas enviar datos de dos entidades podrias unirlas en una `class` como ser

```
public class PresupuestoReporte{
   public Presupuesto Presupuesto {get;set;}
   public Cliente Cliente {get;set;}
}
```

teniendo la clase entonces quedaria

```
public partial class FormPresupuesto : Form
{
    public FormPresupuesto()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }        

    private void FormPresupuesto_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        PresupuestoReport reportData = new PresupuestoReport();
        reportData.Presupuesto = SqliteDataAccess.BuscarUltimoPresupuestoCreado()[0];
        reportData.Cliente = SqliteDataAccess.BuscarClientePorDNI(ultimo.ClienteDNI)[0];

        this.ClienteBindingSource.DataSource = reportData;
        this.reportViewer1.RefreshReport();
    }

}
```

por supuesto actualiza el reporte para que use la nueva clase `PresupuestoReporte` y asi tener ambos datos en el reporte

Un ejemplo que hace hacer uso de class como origen de datos

[ReportViewer y Rdlc, ejemplo Factura (datos fijos)](http://joseluisgarciab.blogspot.com/2013/10/reportviewer-y-rdlc-ejemplo-facturacion.html)

Nota: el nombre de la clase puede cambiarlo si necesitas un nombre que se adapte al modelo

Comment: La respuesta parecia correcta, pero no me sirve, ya que a la hora de querer acceder a los datos del cliente no me es posible.
https://i.gyazo.com/ecfbfeb95941c56e36799162148c2ecd.png

Comment: Actualizaste el reporte para que use como esquema de datos esta nueva class ? asi como originalmente defines el reporte para usar las class Cliente o Presupuesto, debes cambiarlo para que use la nueva class que los agrupa

Comment: Si exacto, pero no se puede acceder a los datos del objeto cliente dentro del objeto presupuesto.

Comment: edite la respuesta, puse un link a un articulo donde veras que alli logran acceder a entidades relacionadas, lo unico que veo como diferencia es que se trata de una lista, pero poder se deberia poder

Comment: Perfecto, siguiendo ese enlace si lo he logrado. Muchas gracias ;)